# I'm trying to create custom RPM using SPEC file.

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

demo.spec

```
Name:           demo
Version:        1
Release:        0
Summary:        demo apss

Group:          Applications/Archiving

License:        GPLv2+

URL:            http://xyz.co.in

Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.%{release}.tar.gz

BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)


Requires:       tar

%description


%prep

%setup -q


%build

%configure

make %{?_smp_mflags}


%install

rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%clean

rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files

%defattr(-,root,root,-)

%doc

/demo/


%changelog
```

---

**Output Error**:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IEtaZH

+ umask 022

+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD

+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD

+ rm -rf demo-1

+ /bin/tar -xf -

+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/demo-1.0.tar.gz

+ STATUS=0

+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'

+ cd demo-1

/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IEtaZH: line 34: cd: demo-1: No such file or directory

**error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IEtaZH (%prep)**
```

**RPM build errors**:

```
`Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IEtaZH (%prep)`
```

Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having an issue due to how your tarball is structure. This section is the relevant area:

```
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/demo-1.0.tar.gz

+ STATUS=0

+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'

+ cd demo-1
```

So the failure is when you try to move into that directory with setup, it expects that directory (demo-1) to exist within your tarball. The spec file you have provided is incomplete and will continue to provide errors even after you resolve this. You should review the [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/RPM-HOWTO/build.html) and [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) documentation before you attempt to build this again.

There was a similar question asked [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261565/newbie-rpmbuild-error) previously.